# How to analyze difference in dependent variables

Tags: multiple-regression

In a simple scenario I'm analyzing impressions and click thru rate (CTR) of banner advertisements.  Multiplying these together equals the number of clicks.

Say I have the following example dataset

[image]

And I want to figure out what was the cause of our clicks decreasing from day 1 to day 2.  Clicks are effected by both Impressions and CTRs, and they both dropped.  My question is, how can i quantify in a reasonable way which metric had a bigger effect and by how much?

I would like to be able to say.  "Our loss in clicks was x% due to a drop in impressions, and y% due to a loss in CTR" (where x + y = 1)

If someone could walk through this problem, or even give some topics to google for would be helpful.

(I had no idea what to tag this, I will change it when I figure out if this is even a real type of problem)

*update: updated example data*

Comment: I would be surprised if the CTR wasn't computed as clicks/impressions, so it doesn't make sense to me to think of these as independent contributions. From day 1 to 2, it looks like the CTR is constant.

Comment: @gung I changed the example data so the CTRs weren't so close, but you are correct CTR is computed as clicks/impressions.  I'm looking for the ability to create like a pie chart to visualize the problem 'why did clicks drop from day 1 to 2', the answer is either that we didn't show the banner enough (impressions), or that people didn't like the banner (didn't click it..CTR).  In this example it is a combo of both, but I want to be able to calculate which one had a bigger effect, and by how much.  I hope that clarifies a bit of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. Here's a proof.

Let $i_1$, $i_2$, $t_1$, $t_2$ be the number of impressions and clickthrough rates (respectively) at time 1 and time 2 (respectively). Since each number of clicks $c_j = i_jt_j$, we want to find $x ∈ [0, 1]$ such that

$c_2 - c_1 = i_2t_2 - i_1t_1 = x(i_2 - i_1) + (1 - x)(t_2 - t_1)$ .

(The other weight, $y$, is just $1 - x$.) Solving the equation for $x$ shows that

$x = \frac{(1 - i_1) t_1 + (i_2 - 1) t_2}{t_2 - t_1 - i_2 + i_1}$ .

But now if we let $i_1 = 200$, $t_1 = 110/i_1$, $i_2 = 820$, and $t_2 = 74/i_2$, we get $x = -.06$, contradicting the desired property that $x ∈ [0, 1]$.